# Send data through AJAX using react Flux architechture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, flux

```
Following is my react code:
var AddRecord = React.createClass({
               getInitialState: function() {
                        return {
                          Data: []
                        }
                    },

                sendData : function() {

               //AJAX Code
                },        

                fieldHandle : function(event){
                  var cellData = event.target.value;
                  console.log(cellData);
                     Data : cellData
                 }.bind(this),

                render: function() {
                  return (
                           <form onSubmit={this.sendData()} name="AddRecord" method="post">
                              <table><tr><td>Enter Id</td><td><input type="text" onChange={this.fieldHandle} name="name"/></td></tr>
                                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td></tr>
                              </table>
                            </form>
                  );
            }
        });

        React.render(<AddRecord/>, document.getElementById('form-data'));
```

I want to write the AJAX code to send the data to the process.php. I think, I should use flux architecture for this.So help me to install flux and writing the code to send the data.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have a conceptual misunderstanding about Flux. Flux is a design pattern to help you manage your state. There are many different implementations of flux. (e.g. Redux, Reflux, Alt.) If you want to use flux, pick a framework and read up on it. However, be aware that Flux is not an AJAX library. For AJAX capability, you'll need a library specifically for that. (e.g. jQuery, SuperAgent, Fetch.)

Comment: @DavidWalsh May i know how to use AJAX to send the data in reactJS

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define your `sendData` method so that it contains an AJAX submission.

```
sendData: function() {
    var name = this.refs.nameField.value;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/submit',
        data: {
            name: name
        }
    }).done(function () {
        // set state to indicate success
    }).fail(function () {
        // set state to indicate failure
    });
}
```

I'll leave it you to figure how to define the `done` and `fail` callbacks.

Of course you don't have to use jQuery for AJAX. It might appropriate to use a smaller library like SuperAgent instead.

Finally, note the use of `this.refs.nameField.value`. References are a feature of React. You just need to define your input with a `ref` attribute.

```
<input ref="nameField" type="text" name="name" />
```

Comment: I had got error: TypeError: this.refs.nameField is undefined
 

<div id="form-data"></div>

Comment: You need to place the reference on the input tag as shown in the last line of answer. Also, change `onSubmit={this.sendData()}` to `onSubmit={this.sendData}`.